# How to use a button to delete a "to do" list item that was added through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding trying create a delete button to delete the corresponding list item. I've tried trying to make a for loop to iterate through the list items but there are no items to begin with, so no array to iterate through. not sure if my logic is right here or I'm overlooking something.

This is my code, what do I need to do to make the delete button work?

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
    <form id="taskForm">
      <input id="taskInput"></input>
      <button type="button" id="taskButton">Click Here</button>  
     </form>
     <ul id="taskLister"></ul>
</div>


<script>
    let button = document.getElementById("taskButton");
    button.addEventListener('click', () => taskList());

    function taskList() {
      let item = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
      let newTask = document.createElement("li");
      let deleteTaskButton = document.createElement("button");
      deleteTaskButton.innertext = item;
      newTask.innerText = item;
      document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(newTask);
      document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(deleteTaskButton);

      if(markTaskComplete) {
        newTask.addEventListener('click', (e) => markTaskComplete(e));
        deleteTaskButton.addEventListener('click', (i) => removeTask(i));
      }
    }


    function markTaskComplete(e) {
      let strikeThrough = e.target;
      strikeThrough.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }


    function removeTask(i) {
      let deleteTask = i.target;
      deleteTask.parentNode.removeChild(li);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you just need to make a couple of changes to get it to work:

1. Add the `deleteTaskButton` as a child of the `newTask` list item. You are adding it as a sibling, but if we make it a child then this associates it directly with the `li` element, so we can easily find the `li` you want to delete:

```
    function taskList() {
      [...]
      document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(newTask);
      newTask.appendChild(deleteTaskButton);  // 1. add to the new task li
      [...]
    }
```

2. Now in your `removeTask` function, the clicked button that gets passed in is a child of the `li` you have chosen to delete, so you just need to get its parent element and remove it:

```
function removeTask(i) {
  let deleteTask = i.target.parentElement;
  deleteTask.remove();
}
```

That's all you need!

**Working Example:**

```js
let button = document.getElementById("taskButton");
button.addEventListener('click', () => taskList());

function taskList() {
  let item = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
  let newTask = document.createElement("li");
  let deleteTaskButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteTaskButton.textContent = "Delete "+item;
  newTask.innerText = item;
  document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(newTask);
  newTask.appendChild(deleteTaskButton);    /* 1. ADD BUTTON TO LI */

  if (markTaskComplete) {
    newTask.addEventListener('click', (e) => markTaskComplete(e));
    deleteTaskButton.addEventListener('click', (i) => removeTask(i));
  }
}


function markTaskComplete(e) {
  let strikeThrough = e.target;
  strikeThrough.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}

function removeTask(i) {
  /* 2. THE BUTTON IS NOW A CHILD OF THE LI, SO DELETE ITS PARENT */
  let deleteTask = i.target.parentElement;
  deleteTask.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <form id="taskForm">
    <input id="taskInput"></input>
    <button type="button" id="taskButton">Click Here</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="taskLister"></ul>
</div>
```

Also FYI, to add the text to a button, you use `textContent` instead of `innertext`, e.g.

```
deleteTaskButton.textContent = "Delete "+item;
```

Comment: @Kaelix FYI, I notice your code is not setting the text in the button, so I've updated my answer to include that - see the very end  of the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the delete button while rendering the list items. You can later add an event listener to each button which can be used to delete the items. Here is the code snippet:
(myLeads is an array)

```
function render(leads) {
    let listItems = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
        listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a>
                <button class="delete-item-btn" data-index="${i}">Delete</button>
            </li>
        `;}
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
    const deleteItemBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-item-btn");
    deleteItemBtns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            const index = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
            myLeads.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
            render(myLeads);
        });});}
```